# How can I create a this smooth version of High Pass filter in frequency domain like this

Tags: python, filter, fft

I use np.fft.fft2 to get frequency domain and want to apply a high pass filter on that, but the mask is just a circle with number zero and others with number 1, so it has ringing effect on the resulting image when converting back.

[image]

So how can I create such a smoothed version of this filter like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some functions you can use to generate a 2d Gaussian distribution:

```
def gaussian_2d(x, y, mu1, mu2, sig):
    return np.exp(- (np.power(x - mu1, 2) + np.power(x - mu2, 2)) / (2 * np.power(sig, 2)))

def gen_gaussian_2d_filter(size, radius):
    grid = [[0] * size for _ in range(size)]
    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size):
            grid[i][j] = gaussian_2d(i, j, size/2, size/2, radius)
    return np.array(grid)
```

The filter you want in that image seems to have `radius` ~ `size/10` but of course you can visualize the filter and tune it. Also a clipping function might be helpful since you might want to keep all the low frequency information, see [`numpy.clip`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html).

Comment: This will only result in a single '1' value though (assuming the circle is what's being passed). It could be better to just use a moving mean filter (i.e. a rectangular window) and convolve that with the above binary filter in both dimensions.

Comment: why this is would only result in a single '1'? Also, a rectangular window would be a good approximation to the filter but it's not radially symmetric so it's not a filter only on the frequency but also the phase.

Comment: Because your Gaussian will only attain the value of 1 when `x=[mu1, mu2]`, whereas the filter shown by the OP has a much larger pass band. I just read that the values are 0 inside the filter and 1 outside (i.e. the filter is inverted), but the point still stands. +1 for the phase filter remark, I'm not sure about the OP's requirements in that regard, he'll have to elaborate a bit.

Comment: well that's why I said `numpy.clip` would be helpful since it can clamp the values. And I believe rescaling should be trivial.